# setting hidden text from server-Node.js(express)/Asp.net-core to read it from client- angular 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, asp.net-core

My(assumption) flow is I'll get a form post method html which will contains TOKEN catching it in server side.

```
    app.post('/callback', (req, res)=> {
    var token = req.body.access_token
    res.cookie('access',token); //instead, i want to set in variable/text field
//res.send('<input type=text name="access_token" value="token" hidden/>')
})
```

Now, I want to get the token from the variable/text-field from client side which is set by server.

1. Is it possible to set a value in a text field? (if so, how?)
2. Is it possible for client side to read a value which is set by the
       server side?
3. Is it a correct process?
4. If any better process, free to suggest.

**Update** : I Just wanna try it in Asp.net core

1. Want to save token in varaible at Controller like

   ```
   {

     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["access_token"]))
     {
       var token = Request.Form["access_token"];

       ViewBag.Message = token.ToString();
     }
     return View();
   }
   ```

View part :

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "CustomeView";
}


<script>
  var message = "@ViewBag.Message";
  console.log(message);
</script>

<a href="@Url.Content("/")">Home</a>
```

After a click on Home link it will redirect to my angular2 index.html

2. Index.html - angular 2 ,
   How to use `message`(Token Value) variable in angular 2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head, one way to do that would be to render you angular page as a template from express using [Pug, Jade or something similar](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html). You can then render a script tag with the assignment to a global variable which you can use inside your angular app. You could also alternatively render your form directly with a hidden input with it's assigned to the token

Pseudo Code:

```
//Route File
app.post('/callback',function(req, res){
    var token = req.body.access_token;
    var template = require('./path/to/template');
    template.render({
         token:token
    })
})


//Template File
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        ....
        <script>var token = "${data.token}";</script>
        .....<!-- Angular and other script includes -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: declaring global variable in angular could be usable in server side also?

Comment: Today, I'm gonna have a look on it, but why to use jade,pug etc i already had `Index.html`, so node js: `var template = require(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
    template.render({
         token:token
    })
});`

could it make sense ? if not, how to include Angular index.html(static file) in Templatefile. @ChiragRavindra

Comment: The template file can be very similar to your existing index file. The only difference will be to make the token variable assignment dynamic. The templating is needed as the template allows you to dynamically inject the variable on the server to the client side.

Comment: Then how to integrate my index file in template file. Cause after storing I want to redirect to index file.`callback > storing the token > Index.html` (need to load html file). previously as mention in above code after storing in cookie I'm calling res.redirect(_//index.html_) @ChiragRavindra

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to set a value in a text field? (if so, how?)

Yes just concatenate token to input value.

```
app.post('/callback', (req, res)=> {
    var token = req.body.access_token
    res.cookie('access',token); //instead, i want to set in variable/text field
res.send('<input type=text name="access_token" value='+token+' hidden/>')
})
```

OR ES6 style:

```
 res.send(`<input type=text name="access_token" value="${token}" hidden/>`)
```

${expression}