# Get user to front end after OAuth Redirect - MEAN stack w/ Angular 2

Tags: node.js, angular, oauth-2.0, passport.js

### Here's the sitch

I've got a handy button on my app that will eventually let you sign in seamlessly with Google. It's a link to `/auth/google` on my Node server, which uses `passportjs` to do authentication, and thus redirects you to the Google url where you authorize the application. Upon successful auth, the redirect url (`auth/google/callback`) is hit and it works up a user object given the user's Google info.

### The quesiton

Now the server can redirect the user to wherever it wants, and however that happens, the Angular app needs to get a user object. As far as I know, I can't put the `user` object in a redirect. What's the best practice for telling my Angular app that the user is auth'd and getting the app a copy of the user object?

I've considered redirecting it to some url on the front end that tells it to call the server asking for a new user object, but for some reason I'm thinking there's a classier way...

Comment: waiting for those questions  :) , sending token through url is a not a good one. mean while have a  [look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44818526/setting-hidden-text-from-server-node-jsexpress-asp-net-core-to-read-it-from-cl) note: not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found this description of how to implement SPA and nodejs-based authentication useful:
https://www.matthewtyler.io/handling-oauth2-with-node-js-and-angular-js-passport-to-the-rescue/

Maybe combine it with JWT stored in a HTTPS cookie instead of sessions:
https://stormpath.com/blog/token-auth-spa